# CURLOPT_TIMEOUT not working for curl_multi

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, timeout, break

The CURLOPT_TIMEOUT option doesn't seem to work when there are multiple handlers:

I execute the handlers via this function:

```
function ExecHandle(&$curlHandle)
{
$flag=null;
do {
curl_multi_exec($curlHandle,$flag);
} while ($flag > 0);
}
```

Now when a server's down, it ignores the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and takes a really long time till it continues (it's stuck the second time it calls `curl_multi_exec($curlHandle,$flag);`).
Is there any way to make the timeout work? Or is there another way to remove the handler if it takes too long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The multi interface didn't support CURLOPT_TIMEOUT until libcurl [7.21.2](http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_21_2)

Comment: Great, thank you. Just updated to the newest version and it works like a charm.
Edit: Another question though. Does the multi interface actually execute multiple urls at the same time? It just seems to go through a list one after another

Comment: That seems like a separate question and one that is answered by libcurl docs already. But the answer is: yes.